# Angular-ui-router, set a parameter in route if it's missing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route that looks like the following:

```
.state('obj.subobj', {
    url: '/subobjs?type',
    templateUrl: '.../...layout.html'
})
```

The `type` parameter is important. If the app directs to this route without that param (i.e., `/subobjs` instead of `/subobjs?type=...`), I want to stop everything and set it to a default value before the template ever loads.

I've tried redirecting in a controller like so:

```
.state('obj.subobj', {
    url: '/subobjs?type',
    templateUrl: '.../...layout.html',
    controller: function($state, $stateParams) {
        if (!$stateParams.type) {
            $state.go('obj.subobj', {type: 'default'});
        }
    }
})
```

This works in that it gets me to the correct page, but the template still loads the first time through when the parameter is not set.

I've also tried setting the default value in the controller above, but that doesn't seem to truly set it.

```
$stateParams.type = 'default'; // OR
$state.params.type = 'default';
```

Thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe you could use two states. One for the empty type and one with type.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible since parameters are optional. If I add a route with `url: '/subobjs' It'll hit it even when the parameter is included.